# К я могу десериализировать LocalDateTime в LocalDate используя REST запрос GET где значение в теле это LocalDateTime, а значение в DTO - LocalDate?

Tags: java, spring, deserialize

Я нашёл много информации о преобразовании / десериализации из LocalDate в LocalDateTime, но не нашел ничего про LocalDateTime в LocalDate, в случае, когда мы используем запрос REST, где ответ содержит значение с форматом LocalDateTime и DTO, где записывается это значение - имеет LocalDate.

DTO которая заполняется из полученного response

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContractDto {
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonProperty(value = "date")
    private LocalDate date;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonProperty(value = "begin_date")
    private LocalDate beginDate;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonProperty(value = "end_date")
    private LocalDate endDate;
}
```

Вот что я получаю в теле ответа (некоторые другие значения удалены для упрощённого чтения)

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "date": "2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00",
            "begin_date": "2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00",
            "end_date": "2025-04-30T00:00:00+03:00"
        },
    ]
}
```

Ошибка, которую я получил

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [ru.tfm.connector.model.dto.ResultDto<ru.tfm.transport.model.dto.connector.ContractDto>] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 12] (through reference chain: ru.tfm.connector.model.dto.ResultDto["result"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->ru.tfm.transport.model.dto.connector.ContractDto["date"])] with root cause
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

Что я пробовал:

1. @JsonParser аннотация
2. @DateFormatAnnotation

Что мне не удалось попробовать:

1. Конвертер для Jackson?
2. Custom deserializer?

Если бы эту задачу можно было решить автоматически (например, с помощью аннотации и т. Д. Без создания чего-то индивидуального), было бы здорово.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Исправил, извините.

Comment: Ну а наименование темы-то?

Comment: пробовали паттерн `"yyyy-MM-dd"` менять на тот, что у вас в JSON?

Comment: сделал замену на yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ но не помогло